# Time Zone Issues with Calculating Daily and Yearly Profit

Tags: datetime, time, timezone, timezone-offset, date-arithmetic

OK here is a hardcore question that me and my friend are debating the proper programming solution for.

Let's say I'm running a business in New York at time UTC-4.

My sales rep based in San Francisco, whose time is 11:00 PM on December 31st, 2013 (which is 1:00 AM, January 1st, 2014 in my time) makes a sale that nets the company $1,000,000 USD. He enters the sale in the system as happening on December 31st, 2013, but really, in my time, it happens on January 1st, 2014.

For my 2013 report, do I include the $1,000,000 USD as profit, or does that go in my 2014 report?

A related question to hone in on the problem... how do most companies calculate daily sales for December 31st? Is it the last 24 hours from midnight in the company's HQ timezone, or is it for December 31st from each of it's market's time zones aggregated?

Further, if you only have the date (YYYY-MM-DD) entered for a sale, how should that be converted stored in UTC, being that a UTC day spreads over two unique dates?

Here's a helpful tool I've used to analyze this question:

http://everytimezone.com/#2013-8-27,-420,6bj

Answer (score 1):

From a *practical* perspective:

- It probably wouldn't matter which business day you recorded the sale. Many business end their days early, not necessarily at the stroke of midnight.
- Some businesses might use the time zone of their headquarters, and some might use the time of the location where the sale was made.  Either approach might be valid.
- Of course, if this is an actual concern then you should ask an accountant or tax attorney.   The answer may be different depending on your industry, state, or country.

As far as the *technical* parts to your question:

- A date without a time or time zone is just a date.  Think of it as a logical position on a calendar - not as a unique moment of instantaneous time.
- Without additional context, you *can't* convert it to UTC.  Or any other time zone for that matter.
- Since UTC is a timekeeping system and not a time zone, then technically there is no such thing as a UTC day, but that is just semantics.  Still, the idea of a "UTC day" would still only cover one calendar "date" - since that is part of the definition of what a "date" is.
- It's just that the "UTC day" doesn't align with a "New York day".  Just like a "New York day" doesn't align perfectly with a "Los Angeles day".
- To blow your mind even more, consider that not every local day is 24 hours.  Due to daylight saving time transitions, a "day" might by 23, 23.5, 24 24.5, or 25 hours long.  Of course most are "standard days" - which are exactly 24 hours.
- If you can keep separate that local time is a position on a calendar, while instantaneous time is universal, then you will find that it all makes sense.
- That site you referenced has a nice visualization, and I reference it a lot.  But IMHO it should have a different name because it doesn't cover *every* time zone.  Use it carefully. See the IANA database discussed the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), which has over 500 zones.
- I don't know what language or database you are using, but you may find the concepts I described recently in [this post on working with Date and Time in RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/kb/61/working-with-date-and-time-in-ravendb) useful.  Specifically, read the section titled "Time Zone Conversions".  Even if you use some other technology, the same concepts will apply.